# Image is not showing in python django project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Image is not showing in python django project due to hardware issue every code is right, images fluctuated how this can be resolved??

```
<div class="owl-carousel" id="slider1">
      {% for b in bottomwears %}
        <a href="{% url 'product-detail' b.id %}" class="btn"><div class="item"><img src="{{b.product_image.url}}" alt="" height="300px"><span class="fw-bold">{{b.title}}</span><br><span class="fs-5">Rs. {{b.discounted_price}}</span></div></a>
      {% endfor %}
     </div>
```

Below is the screen shoot of website where image is not shown.

[image]

**Model Code**

```
class Product(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 selling_price = models.FloatField()
 discounted_price = models.FloatField()
 description = models.TextField()
 brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 category = models.CharField( choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
 product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='productimg')
```

Comment: make sure that the image is uploaded to the media directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you configured `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in `settings.py` file ?
2. You can do an `Inspect` on image and know the URL of the image in the HTML that it is pointing to. This way you could know the issue.

Thanks!